# std::set for each element in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, vector, set

I need a functionality of `std::set` for each element in an array. How can I achieve this functionality?

I started with allocating dynamic array of std set in C++ as follows:

```
set<int>* entry;
```

followed by allocation:

```
entry = (set<int>*)malloc(sizeof(set<int>)*32);
```

No compilation problem, but the runtime fails with segmentation fault when any element is accessed:

```
entry[0].insert(23);
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You haven't created the `set` itself.

Comment: Why not:  std::vector<std::set<int> > entries; ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In c++ you allocate memory with `new`. The difference from malloc here is that the constructor is called to initialize the memory.

```
entry = new set<int>[32];
```

Comment: But don't forget to delete it when you've finished with it. Usually, it's better to use a container like `std::vector` to manage the memory for you.

Answer (score 11):

What about

```
#include <set>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
        std::vector < std::set<int> > entry(32); // std::vector constructor makes 32 calls to std::set<int> constructor
        entry[0].insert(23);
        // std::vector destructor makes 32 calls to std::set<int> destructor
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Even though you've allocated storage for 32 `std::set`'s you haven't initalized this span of memory (ie. the constructor of your `std::set`'s has not been called) therefore the memory you are trying to *operate on/access* in `entry[0].insert (23)` will cause [*undefined behavior*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/1090079).

Mixing C++ objects with `malloc` and it's equivalent is normally (I'm tempted to write "*always*") considered to be bad practice.

Instead turn to `operator new` which will allocate memory and handle construction of your object in a proper manner, also remember to `delete` the memory allocated to release the memory back to your system (and make the object(s) destruct in a true manner).

---

#### The proper way to do it in C++

<sup>*Some answers will contain text saying that you are better of using a `std::vector<std::set>`, though that isn't really an answer to your question so I'll leave you with this example snippet*</sup>

```
int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::set<int> *entries = new std::set<int> [32]; 

  entries[0].insert (123);

  delete [] entries;
}
```

Comment: `std::vector` really is an answer to the question. Your example has a memory leak if `insert` throws an exception; the simplest fix for such a leak is to manage the array with a RAII wrapper; and such a wrapper for a dynamic array is already implemented and called `std::vector`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour it's an answer beyond the scope of the question, therefore I choose not to include it in my post.

Comment: MikeSeymour is right.  This is no longer good practice in C++.  `std::array` is another option for fixed size arrays.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good question, whose answer is not immediately obvious.  The trouble is that each `set` object wants to be initialized before it is used, whereas your code only allocates raw memory for each `set`.  This fixes it:

```
#include <vector>
#include <set>

using std::vector;
using std::set;

const int N = 32;

int main() {
    vector< set<int> > entry(N);
    entry[0].insert(23);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not try to use malloc/calloc/realloc etc with c++ classes. Use new.